# Cannot locate elements on this page. Firebug comes empty with status as loading. How to automate it ? (I wish to click OK)

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I want to automate this page and click Ok Button, but the page is not displaying in HTML in Firebug and status is coming as "Waiting for ..."

In such cases how to automate the click without elements ? Please advice..

[image]

Comment: Is not this an "alert"? Have you tried to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13714614/771848)?

Comment: No we are using Selenium IDE for this test case, we tried SendKeys, ChooseOKonNextConfirmation but it is not working..

Comment: Can you access the source code? Obviously the client has not loaded the page, but if you can read the source from the repository you may be able to determine what kind of warning is displaying and code to it.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no DOM associated with the element that you want to interact with(similar to the one in your case), use Java robot class to send a `{ENTER}`. I believe this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is browser app alert or pop up message. Generally it will not give any response on `alert.accept();`. For this type of alert below approach that can be used :

1. User Desktop automation : User `Robot` or `AutoIt` to click on `OK`
2. As it is Firefox specific, Script can use with Profile :

   ```
   FirefoxProfile customProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
   customProfile.setPreference("dom.disable_beforeunload", true);
   FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(customProfile);
   ```

Let me know if any other scenario happened with this pop up and verify my answer.